# Probability of an even or odd number of claims in a homogeneous Poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

So I'm told that claims arrive in an insurance portfolio to a homogeneous Poisson process with at a rate of $\lambda > 0$ . Let $X(t), t\geq 0$ denote the number of claims that arrive in the time interval $(0,t]$ and let $P_k(t)=P(X(t)=k), \ k=0,1,2,...$

I'm asked to verify that:

- $P(X(t)$ is odd$)=((e^{\lambda t} - e^{-\lambda t})/2)e^{-\lambda t}$
- $P(X(t)$ is even$)= ((e^{\lambda t}+e^{-\lambda t})/2)e^{-\lambda t}$

I'm not really sure at all what I need to do. I know how to answer questions that ask to find the probability of a certain number of claims in a given time period (such as October to December) but  I'm not sure how I can apply that here.

The only idea I can think of is using the general formula: $P(X=k)=(\lambda^k/k!)e^{-\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is the rate of claims and $k$ is the number of claims, maybe I could pair this with the idea that an even number of claims is $2k$ and odd number is $2k-1$?

I also know the probability formula for a non-homogeneous Poisson Process: say we want to find the probability of $k$ claims from $t_1$ to $t_2$ where $t_1,t_2$ are months in the year, then the probability formulas would be: $e^{-(\Lambda(t_2)-\Lambda(t_1))}\cdot (\Lambda (t_2)-\Lambda (t_1)^k)/k!$ which looks quite similar to what they are asking me to verify, but again I'm not sure how I can use this.

Both of these ideas are just guesses so feel free to ignore them if I'm completely off :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the thoughts in *"The only idea I can think of is using the general formula: $P(X=k)=(\lambda^k/k!)e^{-\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is the rate of claims and $k$ is the number of claims,"* together with $e^x=1+x+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^3}{3!}+\cdots$ using $x=\lambda t$ and $x=-\lambda t$

Comment: By definition, $X(t)$ is a Poisson variable with rate $\lambda t$, i.e.,
$$\mathbb P\Bigl(X(t)=k\Bigr)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!},\,k\in\mathbb Z_+.$$
Summing these probabilities over $k$ even (resp. $k$ odd) will make the $(\mathrm e^{\lambda t}\pm\mathrm e^{-\lambda t})/2$ appear.